# Copy matching lines to a second file

Tags: sed, awk

I need to copy all lines in a file matching a pattern to a second file.

In detail: I have a sql dump and want to create a second sql file which includes all commands for tables whose name matches dx_postings, dx_postings_archive, and so on. The pattern should be dx_postings.

Any ideas? I'd prefer an awk or sed solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `sed` solution:

```
sed -ne '/pattern/ p' infile >outfile
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, see this :

```
awk '/pattern/' FILE > NEWFILE
```

more specific :

```
awk '/^(DROP|LOCK) .*dx_postings/' file.sql > newfile.sql
```

If you have **INSERT** or **CREATE** statements, this is more tricky because there's more than one lines.

Comment: I want to have all lines matching the pattern in this file, also LOCK INSERT and the CREATE TABLE statements.

Comment: I want a bear and a pizza. More seriously, consider dumping the DB another one time and add the tables to the command line you'd like to have in the dump. Or consider learning awk.

Comment: Moreover, if you can't dump the DB again, you can create a temporary DB and dumping it then. If you just need to filter a dump for one shot, consider using an editor like `vim`.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed);

```
sed -n '/pattern/w second_file' first_file
```